# Problem with Eclipse while programming for android - "Refreshing external folders"

Tags: android, eclipse, refresh, save

I have set up Eclipse to run as smoothly as possible because I was having a lot of problems with it running out of memory in my last machine. One of the configurations was to have it automatically refresh the workspace every time I save. I don't know if that is the problem but I thought I's mention it.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

It happens every time I open Eclipse and save anything. I was also having another problem with  something to do with my workspace being compliant with Java 1.6 when I need 1.5. But then I switched and the problem went away. This problem then popped up.

Does anyone know any solution to this because it is really getting annoying now.

Comment: Picture is not available anymore. Next time upload to Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Eclipse are you running?  It clearly states in the Android docs that Helios is not supported, so if you are running Helios, that can cause issues.

You also don't specify which OS you are running, and Eclipse runs a more than one platform, so all types of things could be going on based on OS and permissions combinations.

Remember that this site is a lot like entering a bug.. the more information you provide, the better answers you get back.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't realise that the version mattered (out of stupidity) and I forgot the OS because it is happening on Windows 64bit and Ubuntu x86. And yeah it is Helios. Damn. Should I downgrade? Is there any reason why Google hasn't updated?

Answer (score 5):

In case you're still having this problem: Yes, it's a well known bug and it is fixed. But the fix is not included in 3.6.1 yet - it's targeted for 3.6.2.

Workaround is closing all your projects and reopening them. For me (and others from what I gather from their comments) it worked.

Look here for details: [eclipse bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326434)

Comment: Closing the project and reopening it does in fact clear the error (at least in my case). Thanks for reporting this tip :)

Comment: Confirmed with 3.6.1.  this answer should get the check

Answer (score 3):

This is known bug in [eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321358#c7). Update your eclipse to the latest version and it should work fine. If it does not then request to reopen the bug.

Btw, I suggest you to use [Eclipse yoxos](http://ondemand.yoxos.com/geteclipse/start), you can customize your eclipse here and download it. It's bug free. I have been using this from the last 2 years with any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Intellij IDEA and no problems anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Helios release 2 (3.6.2) on XP and Android tool v14.

Whenever I have a project that uses another library project and do a refresh, "Refreshing External Folders" will run for about a minute, which is way too long for frequent builds. I end up directly including the library jar file instead.